# Why has the "Python" chat room been renamed "Python and Robotics"?

Tags: discussion, chat

I noticed that the chat room for Python has been replaced with a chat room labeled "Python & Robotics" https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python-robotics

Was there a lack of space for chat rooms and they needed to be combined? Otherwise, I see no real reason to combine two different things. If someone wants to talk about `Robotics`, there should be a `Robotics` room, if someone wants to talk about `Python` there should be a `Python` room. Combining the two rooms will create chaos - two groups of people talking about two different things in the same place.

**update:** Based on [the suggestion by Manishearth](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157072/192545), I have created [a new chat room for Python](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20309/everything-python).

Comment: Ha, I am as confused as you are. I don't see how the two are connected. It looks like the room owner trying to cover his multiple areas of interest.

Comment: @animuson: Not necessarily. Looks like all of the frequenters of that room are robotics enthusiasts. Python is one of the most used languages in robotics.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was a decision by the room owners. See https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/6446570#6446570.

The room wasn't merged, it was simply renamed to add another topic. It's up to the room owners to change the room name/topic as they wish (though they generally, as in this case, follow the suggestions of the room regulars)

If you don't like it, let the room owner know. He may revert or give you a reason for keeping the new name.

Comment: so it is possible then, to create another chat room simply called "Python" ?

Comment: @InbarRose: Sure. Go to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/new . Though I see no reason why you can't continue using the old room. Python discussion will continue most probably.

Comment: created a new chat room for python here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20309/everything-python

Comment: @InbarRose Earlier a Robotics room was present on SO. This was frozen due to inactivity. I suggested that Robotics be added to the room name. Did not know about the robotics site existence.

Answer (score 15):

Can this be changed back now? There's been no chat in the room for a couple of weeks; instead there's been a lot of activity in the newly-created [Everything Python](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/20309/everything-python) room. This has been the Python chat room for years, and adding "and Robotics" doesn't seem to have done much good.

The Python chat room was the sixth room created on the site. It's annoying to see the activity suddenly jump to a different room. If nothing else, it makes searching through the history of Python chat on Stack Overflow more difficult.

*Update:* The room [has been renamed](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/7326452#7326452) back to "Python". I hope the participants will move back.

Comment: While we're doing this, we could also add the owners of the "Everything Python" room as owners of the "Python" room.

Comment: The [owner](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/705339/kneel-before-zod) of the 'Python and Robotics' room has been absent from SO for about 10 days or so. But yes, the recent surge in Python chatters suggests that the original room should be reverted to its original name. Also merging the two rooms, 'Python and Robotics' and 'Everything Python' would be nice.

Comment: Balpha has now added Ingbar Rose and myself as owners of the older Python room too; I've pinged the original owner to see what he has to say about that. Perhaps a merge is possible / workable.