# Chat room merge request: Everything Python into Python

Tags: support, stack-overflow, chat

For a while now, there have been [2 Python chatrooms on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157071/why-has-the-python-chat-room-been-merged-to-python-and-robotics), after a (mis-judged?) rename by a slow-to-respond owner of the original room.

I'm now one of the owners of the new 'Everything Python' room, and balpha made us owners of the old room as well. I [asked the original owner](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/7493505#7493505) for feedback nearly 2 weeks ago on the possibility of a merge of the two rooms, but have received no response.

The consensus among the room regulars is that a merge would be in the best interest of the Python community on SO. The new room has a set of active regulars that I think will drive the community actively and responsibly; there is even a wiki to act as a community notice board in the works.

I know us room owners can move individual messages over between rooms, but that is going to get tedious fast. Can a moderator or SE dev help out here and:

- Move over *all* messages from the [Everything Python room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20309/everything-python) (id 20309) to the [Python room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) (id 6).
- If possible, move over or merge people's favourites from the new to old room, so that they automatically will join the target room in the future?
- If possible, redirect anyone joining the Everything Python room to the old Python room. A big fat notice with link would suffice.
- Freeze the Everything Python room.

Comment: Mods cant merge rooms. You need dev powa. I dunno if you _need_ to merge, why not just tell your room community to migrate themselves?

Comment: @Manishearth: Because preserving the transcripts in one place counts for something. It's the preferred option, *if possible*. If not, so be it.

Comment: As the original owner of the new 'Everything Python' room I completely support this move.

Comment: If @balpha finds this easy enough to do, it should be something one room owner can initiate and another room owner agree to in order for it to happen in the future. While this is the first time I've seen such a request, I can't help thinking there will be more. Note, that's a **big** `if`.

Comment: moving all messages will create a mess in the merged room.  When 2 separate conversations, and active times occurred, there could be mass confusion when looking at the transcript.  Why not just migrate all the users over, and leave the other room for reference?

Comment: @KyleTrauberman: Yeah, I actually agree. I didn't want to draw too much attention to the extraneous room though as we were managing to let it slip into frozen state by *not* posting in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By providing my own ['big fat notice'](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/20309/2013/2/10), the 'merge' was managed all by our lonesome selves. As of [1:15 AM this morning](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/20309) the "Everything Python" room was frozen after 2 weeks of inactivity.

The regulars have found their way across to the 'original' room, and I guess the old transcripts will forever be available in the frozen room.

This means that things are now fine, hunky-dory and swell. We can all move on and enjoy our thriving Python chat room. No further merge actions are required.